# Showing an image preview in Android

Tags: android, image, gallery

I want to show the images that are on the phone to the user. but I want to show the user a preview of the images.

[image]

And when the user touches an image, I want to show a path of the image.

I have a button in my layout. how can show the images, when click the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/back_default">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/button_pickimage" android:id="@+id/btn_pickimage"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

This should offer a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at
[Android Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) and [Android GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

When you click the button just put Intent to direct to GridView.

And about clicking the image to show its path is another different thing. You could build a custom layout or Toast or whatever to meet your need to show the path. Put onClick listener on the Image to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to show the thumbnail image first(as shown in your link) and by clicking any of image should enlarge that particular image in a different view,

Then simple approach..

```
1.Make two separate activity for preview and large image
2. Store all your image in a array(If you have diff images for preview and large image then place accordingly).
3. set id for each imageview (In preview mode)
4. send id of selected imageview to next activity using putextra
5. Use id to access the array
```